# Deployement impossible on Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7

I have a big problem with Websphere. When I try to deploy an update of my application, a error occured :

> [09/08/11 11:19:19:240 CEST] 00000015 annotations   E
>   ArchiveInputStreamData iterate unable to process input stream
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.ClassScanner.scanInputStream(ClassScanner.java:235)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl$1.applyTo(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:260)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.amm.scan.context.ArchiveInputStreamData.iterate(ArchiveInputStreamData.java:241)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.scan(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:258)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.scan(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:219)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.processAnnotations(WARFileImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:248)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppDeploymentUtil.getModuleVersion(AppDeploymentUtil.java:1458)
>     at
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.application.AppDeploymentUtil.isEE5SchemaDD(AppDeploymentUtil.java:1419)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkIfEE5ModulesContainXMIBindings(AppInstallHelper.java:1098)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkIfEE5ModulesContainXMIBindings(AppInstallHelper.java:1063)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:324)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getAppDeploymentInfoGenericRead(AppInstallHelper.java:469)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.DefaultBindingHelper.getDefaultBindingInfo(DefaultBindingHelper.java:101)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.DefaultBindingHelper.getDefaultBindingInfo(DefaultBindingHelper.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.UploadAction.formUpload(UploadAction.java:491)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.action.UploadAction.execute(UploadAction.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:933)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:500)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:321)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)+

I don't understand the origin of problem. No Jar is added. Only two functions have been added.

Do someone know why Websphere bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem...
With WebSphere, the tags in the web.xml  must be in a specific order.
Indeed, my tag `<welcome-file-list>` was before the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` tags.
So I changed the order, and it's working...

Comment: What tags are you referring two? Did you have an error in your web.xml ?

Comment: For WAS the web.xml must have this order: 
1. Description
2. Session attributes
3. Servlets
4. Servlet mapping
5. Resources
6. context Param
7. Listeners
8. Filters
9. Error pages
10. welcome pages

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search found [this IBM PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM40985) which seems to be the same symptoms.

Comment: I saw that, but in the IBM page, the problem occurs while starting. I've the problem on deployement, and when i want to lauch my webapp, i've lots of errors (classes not found essentialy).
I've tried too to change log level for "finer" and nothing about my classes appears in there.

Comment: The annotation scanning component is used during both deployment and start.  PM40985 is only available in 7.0.0.19 and 8.0.0.1, which have not been released yet.  You either need to open a PMR with IBM to get an iFix, or you need to wait for the fixpaks to be released.  In the meantime, you might try progressively chopping out more and more class files from the JAR to find the one that is causing problems.